# How to capture multiple digits/characters with linux/bash?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I am most familiar with Ruby Regular Expressions so I thought capturing regex expressions in linux would be easier. However, I can't seem to get it right.

How do I catch 0 or more digits in linux and 0 or more characters in linux?

As an example, I want to capture this expression:

```
/p/foobar/contributors/33845829/commits
```

So far the regex I have that sort of captures it is the following

```
p/[a-z/A-Z]/contributors/[1-9]
```

I know for a fact this is wrong because when I append `commits` to the end, results end up with 0. When I try to do something like this `*[a-zA-Z]` or `*[1-9]`, I get nothing either. I know I'm doing it wrong but I could use just a little push to move on with my work. Thanks.

Comment: Try with `p/[a-z/A-Z]+/contributors/[0-9]+`

Comment: try a `+` for one or more, eg, [0-9]+; try a `*` for zero or more, eg, [0-9]*

Comment: What tool are you using in Linux for regex matching. What is your expected match?

Comment: AND show a context data set that includes your target match. Good luck.